# display data on page when user is auth, express , jwt, cookie-parser

Tags: express, cookies, jwt

I have simple application where user can register and login in his acc, now i want display user login on page, how  i can get data from db about user that authinticated now

i also use mongodb and moongose as database

this register sistem

```
router.post('/register',async (req,res)=>{

    const {login,mail,password} = req.body

    bcrypt.hash(password, 10).then((hash) =>{
        User({login:login,password:hash,mail:mail}).save()
    })
    res.redirect('/login')
})
```

this is login sistem

```
router.post('/',async (req,res)=>{
    const {mail, password } = req.body
    const user = req.body
    console.log(user)
    const isUserExist = await User.findOne({mail:mail})
    const UserPwdCorrect = isUserExist.password

    if(!isUserExist){
        console.log('Логин гавно')
    } else{
         bcrypt.compare(password,UserPwdCorrect).then((match)=>{
        if(!match){
            console.log("Пароль говно")
        } else{

            const accessToken = createToken(user)
            res.cookie("token",accessToken,{
                maxAge:60*60*24*30*1000
            })

        res.redirect('/')
        }
    })
    }
})
```

and this is what i did in jwt.js file

```
const {sign,verify} = require("jsonwebtoken")


const createToken = (user) =>{
    const accessToken = sign({login: user.login, isAdmin:user.idAdmin,id:user.id},"jwt-secret")
    return accessToken
}

const validateToken = (req,res,next) =>{
    const accessToken = req.cookies["token"] 
    console.log(accessToken)
    if(accessToken){
        try {
            const validtoken = verify(accessToken,"jwt-secret")
            if(validtoken){
                req.authenticated = true
                return next()
            } else{
                return next()
            }
        } catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

Pass in userID in the JWT token. When the user clicks on the profile page, send a POST request to an endpoint that accepts the token (in a header). The backend verifies the token, extracts the userID, makes the DB call, and finally returns the response.

An advantage to this approach is that your profile route is authenticated (i.e, the route is secure).